# Making pypy available to pyscripter (or any other ide for that matter) on Windows?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pypy, pyscripter

Maybe I am missing something, but I just downloaded pypy 2.0 beta2 windows binary (32 bit), and it seems I can run the interpreter by executing pypy.exe. However, I would like pypy to work with pyscripter and for all my old libraries to be available. Is this possible? Or is it as if I just installed a new version of python (so I would need to install all of my libraries again)? I might be confused at a fundamental level.

Thanks!

Comment: have you tried setting the `PYTHONPATH` variable?

Answer (score 3):

It's not "as if". :-) You installed a new version of Python. Yes, you will have to install all your libraries again.

It seems you tell PyScripter which Python it uses for debugging with the PYTHONHOME variable. Try this:

```
SET PYTHONHOME=C:\<PathtoPyPy>
PyScripter --PYTHON27 --PYTHONDLLPATH "C:\<PathtoPyPy>" %1 %2 %3 %4 %5
```

Comment: I get the following message when I do this: 'Error 126: Could not open Dll "python27.dll"'. And as a side, would any library that works on python2.7 work on pypy?

Comment: It worked, actually. I started pyscripter manually (via start menu), and found the version of python to be '2.7.4 (default, Apr  6 2013, 19:54:46) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)]' and my libraries missing (first time I am happy with missing libraries). Thanks!

Comment: @kyphos That doesn't sound like you are using PyPy in that case. I'm guessing --PYTHON27 should say something else, but you will have to as the PyScripter developers. Perhaps try with only setting PYTHONHOME and not have the paremeters?

Comment: Yeah caught on to this earlier today, I will try asking the pyscripter devs (or alternatively, I'll just write code using pyscripter then just manually execute them using pypy).

Answer (score 0):

PyCharm Community edition IDE by JetBrains supports pypy, or any other interpreter

Just go to File > Settings > Project INterpreter and set interpreter location